# How do I perform custom build steps in Flex Builder 3?

Tags: flexbuilder

I want to do some of the things in Flex Builder 3 that I would use custom build steps for in Visual Studio. They aren't in the project properties and Google is not much help either.

Is it possible to add custom build steps in Flex Builder 3 or Eclipse more generally? If so, now do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

[The Advanced Build Options section](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/build_6.html#139360) of the Flex documentation indicates you can create custom builders in Flex Builder using Apache Ant.

Additional information about using Ant with Eclipse can be found on [Simon Whatley's blog](http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/using-ant-with-eclipse)